# angular 2 alert box on click event by referencing the value in textbox

Tags: angular, if-statement, input, buttonclick

Hi I want to display an alert box on clicking a button, where the value should be taken from the input text box.

Here is the code..

### This is the file in app.component.html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>No of Units Used:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="electricity"> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="checkbox"/>Home <br>
  <input type="checkbox"/>Commercial <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" (click)="return calculate()">
</table>
```

### Now the logic which I wrote in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Electricity Bill Claculation';
    electricity: any;
     msg: any = 'please enter the units';
  calculate()
   {
    let electricity = this.electricity ? parseFloat(this.electricity):0;

   if (electricity!=null  ) {
    alert('hii');
   }else {
   alert ('you entered the value');
   }

   //return  this.electricity;

   }
   }
```

Now I want to use the value of input box and display a alert box where the logic is written in a function in .ts file.

I don't know what are directives to use and I need to write the logic in .ts file rather than using **ngif** in enter code here html file.

I tried all ways which I know and guys anyone do help me in solving this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using bootstraps, take a look at modal. 
if you using material, take a look at MdDialogRef as below sample

confirmation-yes-no-dialog.component.ts

```
   @Component({
        selector: 'app-confirmation-dialog',
        templateUrl: './confirmation-yes-no-dialog.component.html'
    })
    export class ConfirmationYesNoDialogComponent implements OnInit {
        public title: string;
        public message: string;
        public btnOkText?: string;
        public btnCancelText?: string;
        constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmationYesNoDialogComponent>) { }
        ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

confirmation-yes-no-dialog.component.html, you may design it with your own css

```
<div fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutGap="2em">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column"  fxLayoutAlign="stretch center" >
        {{message}}
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" >
        <button md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">{{btnOkText}}</button>
        <button md-raised-button md-dialog-close (click)="dialogRef.close()">{{btnCancelText}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

confirmation-yes-no-dialog.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationYesNoDialogService {

    constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) { }

    public confirmWithoutContainer(title: string, message: string, btnOkText: string = 'Ok', btnCancelText: string = 'Cancel'): Observable<boolean> {

        let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmationYesNoDialogComponent>;
        let config = new MdDialogConfig();
        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationYesNoDialogComponent, config);

        dialogRef.componentInstance.title = title;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.message = message;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.btnOkText = btnOkText;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.btnCancelText = btnCancelText;

        return dialogRef.afterClosed();
    }
}
```

register it as a service

to use it,

```
constructor(private _confirmationDialog: ConfirmationYesNoDialogService) {
 }
this._toasterService.showSuccess('Site Notification successfully created and updated');
this._toasterService.showError('Error creating Site Notification');
```

or u can use MdSnackBar as a toaster.